# C returns incorrect float value after function returns

Tags: c

Firstly, i don't believe this is related to precision, I think the variable is losing scope somehow?

**The function below, header file sorting.h:**

```
#ifndef SORTING_H
#define SORTING_H

/*===========================================================================
Function        find_median
Description:    median values in a  sorted array.
==========================================================*/
float find_median(float values[],int n );

#endif /* SORTING_H */
```

**Implementation file sorting.c :**

```
#include  "sorting.h"

float find_median(float values[],int n)
{ 
    float val = 0.0f; 
    // check for even case 
    if (n % 2 == 0) 
    {
     val = (float)values[n/2]; 
    }
    else
    {
        int low_index = (n)/2; 
        int high_index=  low_index + 1; 
        val = (values[low_index] + values[high_index])/2.0f;
    }

    return val; 

}
```

**Main entry, main.c:**

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    //unsorted
    float output_array[] = { 3, 17, 13, 6, 9, -1, 10, 10 };

    int row_length = sizeof(output_array) / sizeof(output_array[0]);

    //sort
    quicksort_iterative(output_array, row_length);

    float median = 0.0f;
    //get the median
    median =  find_median(output_array, row_length);

    printf("median=%f", median);
}
```

**Output:**

sorted:,-1.000000,3.000000,6.000000,9.000000,10.000000,10.000000,13.000000,17.000000
median=6422100.000000

I'm attempted to assign the final median value from as a return value & also as tried passing median as a parameter but both attempts return incorrect values.

The median should be 11.

Comment: Please fix your formatting... it's not clear what code you're running. If it is as quoted, you are not assigning the result of `find_median` to the variable `median`

Comment: Is your function named median() or find_median()

Comment: What is the purpose of the median parameter that you pass by value? Did you mean to pass by reference? Is this really `c` or are you using `c++`?

Comment: OT: You should avoid naming the function and variable the same.

Comment: In fact, it shouldn't even compile if you do that.

Comment: Also, the median should be 9.5, and you have the even/odd cases backwards.

Comment: `floor(n-1)/2` and `ceil(n-1)/2` are wrong

Comment: What you want are `floor((n-1)/2.0)` and `ceil((n-1)/2.0)`

Comment: `median = median(output_array, row_length);`? Your compiler let you do that?

Comment: @Amadeus, the formatting is fixed apologies, let's get to the actual question of why float value is changing after return.

Comment: @cyber101 What is `quicksort_iterative` doing? Without it, your code is not behaving like you have described: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7cdf89f31584b2ae

Comment: Its sorting the values. The output is correct for the sort, you can see that in output that I have posted. Before finding the median you must 1st sort.

Comment: @Amadeus, i commented  out quicksort_iterative, obviously the number are not sorted anymore, however im still getting median=6422104.000000.

Comment: @cyber101 you are having an UB in code not showed here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confused on a number of basic fronts. To begin with, look at your function `find_median`, and specifically at the parameters: (presuming you actually meant to name your function `float_median` instead of just `median` as written in `sorting.c`)

```
 float float_median(float values[],int n, float median);
```

Your function takes an array of `float` as the first parameter, that's fine. (but could simply be written as `float *values` as an array is converted to a pointer on access, see: [C11 Standard - 6.3.2.1 Other Operands - Lvalues, arrays, and function designators(p3)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.1p3) -- it works the same for C++)

Now your second parameter `int n` passing the number of elements in the array (also fine), but your third parameter `float median`, is effectively unused in `float_median`. Assigning `median = val;` has zero effect as in C parameters are **passed by value** so the assignment in `float_median` of `median = val;` simply changes the value **of the copy** of `median` used in the function and has **zero effect** on the original `median` in `main()`. You are returning the value of median from your function so simply drop the third parameter, e.g.

```
#include <math.h>

#include  "sorting.h"

float find_median (float *values, int n)
{ 
    float val = 0; 

    // check for even case 
    if (n % 2 == 0) 
        val = (float)values[n/2]; 
    else {
        int low_index = floor(n-1)/2; 
        int high_index = ceil(n-1)/2; 
        val = (values[low_index] + values[high_index]) / 2.;
    }

    return val; 
}
```

(**note:** also the denominator is changed from `2` to `2.0` to eliminate the resulting cast to avoid integer division)

Good job on your use of *header-guards* to prevent multiple inclusion of `sorting.h`. You only need to update the function prototype to be consistent with dropping the third parameter, e.g.

```
#ifndef SORTING_H
#define SORTING_H

/*===========================================================================
Function        find_median
Description:    median values in a  sorted array.
==========================================================*/
float find_median (float values[], int n);

#endif /* SORTING_H */
```

In your `main()` (I called it `sort.c`) you attempt to use a `quicksort_iterative` function that you do not provide. Forget it, just write a quick compare function for the elements in `output_array` and then use the standard `qsort` function to sort your array, e.g.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "sorting.h"

int compare (const void *a, const void *b)
{
    return (*(int*)a > *(int*)b) - (*(int*)a < *(int*)b);
}

int main (void) {

    float output_array[] = { 3, 17, 13, 6, 9, -1, 10, 10 };
    int row_length = sizeof output_array / sizeof *output_array;

    //sort 
    qsort (output_array, row_length, sizeof *output_array, compare); 

    float median = find_median (output_array, row_length); 

    for (int i = 0; i < row_length; i++)
        printf (i ? " %g" : "%g", output_array[i]);
    putchar ('\n');

    printf ("\nmedian = %.2f\n", median);
}
```

Now just compile:

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=c11 -Ofast sorting.c -o bin/sort sort.c
```

(**note:** I would also recommend including `-Wshadow` to catch any shadowed variables)

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/sort
-1 3 6 9 10 10 13 17

median = 10.00
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions. If you are on windows or using another compiler than gcc/clang, let me know and I can post equivalent compile options for you.

Answer (score 3):

You seem to want to modify `median` in the calling function. In C++, all you simply do is:

```
float median(float values[],int n, float& median)
```

C is a little harder. For that you need a pointer:

```
float median(float values[],int n, float *median)
{
    // ...
    *median = val;
    // ...
}
// ...
find_median(output_array, row_length, &median);
```

Comment: so, why return float?

Comment: There's no reason to do it this way, just use the return value.

Comment: @Barmar, I initially used a return value but that was returning 6422100.000000. Then I attempted to pass in reference, that was returning 0.

Comment: I don't know. I didn't write either function. I'm just saying that based on the code they have shown, the OP seeks to change the value of `median` from inside the function. If that's what they want to do, then this is how they need to do it.

Answer (score 1):

I think there's problem in your formula. try this.

```
float median(float values[],int n) //, float& median)  //note: notice the & here.
{ 
    float val = 0.0f; 
    // check for even case 
    if (n % 2 == 0) 
    {
        //get the average of the 2 mid values.
        int high_index = n/2;
        int low_index = high_index - 1;
        val = (values[high_index] + values[low_index])/2.0f;  
        //note: 2 is integer, 2.0f is float. there might be problem if you use 2 speciall in division.

        printf("even case: val=%f\n", val);
        printf("values[%d]=%f\n",low_index);
        printf("values[%d]=%f\n",high_index);

    }
    else
    {

        val = values[n/2]; 
        printf("odd case: val=%f\n", val);

    }
    //median = val;   //2 way output?
    return val; 

}
```

**Update**
I added logs on the code to trace what's the cause of the problem.

Comment: appreciate the input i tried your algorithm, im still getting back float find_median(float values[],int n). I also removed the 2 way output. The reason for the 2 way out was to attempt and resolve this issue.

Comment: try to run with logs on the `median()`. i think there's some weird on `quicksort_iterative(output_array, row_length);`. or you should use `float values*` instead of `float values[]` in the parameter.

Answer (score 0):

The function is called `find_median` in the header, but `median` in the implementation... how does it link?

Then, you are not assigning the result of `find_median` to the variable `median`

Comment: He is assigning it, but he formatted the question poorly so it's hard to see. He calls the function twice, assigning it the second time.

Comment: never mind, now that I fxed the formatting I see that the assignment is commented out.

Comment: The reason, it was called twin was due bad formatting, I meant to comment out one of the attempts. Regardless in the debugger the value is correct, but when the function returns it printed out incorrectly.